# how can I use <xsl:param> & <xsl:with-param> to copy a node into the new XML with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

I don't even know if this is possible, and I also know that there is a much easier way to do it, but I need to copy a xml node using xsl:param & xsl:with-param.

I have this XML as input :

```
<TR>
    <COMPANY name="FIRST">
        <CODE>k</CODE>
    </COMPANY>
    <COMPANY name="SECOND">
        <CODE>h</CODE>
    </COMPANY>
    <COMPANY name="third">
        <CODE>d</CODE>
    </COMPANY>
</TR>
```

And I have to copy just the element with the attribute name SECOND, and have an output like :

```
<TR>
    <COMPANY name="SECOND">
        <CODE>h</CODE>
    </COMPANY>
</TR>
```

I have this really simple XSLT that does that :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//COMPANY[@name='SECOND']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But as I said I HAVE to use xsl:param & xsl:with-param to copy the node, Im trying this XSLT, and dont know at all if this is even correct or not :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
 <xsl:param name="key" select="//COMPANY[@name='SECOND']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-template>
   <xsl:with-param name="$key"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What exactly is your constraint? Why do you "HAVE to use xsl:param & xsl:with-param"? Where is the parameter value supposed to come from? The code you have posted makes very little sense and consequently so does the question.

Comment: BTW, your "really simple XSLT that does that" does NOT produce the result you show (the `TR` root element is missing).

Comment: Saying that you have to do it using xsl:param and xsl:with-param is a bit like saying that you need to inflate your tyres with a screwdriver. On the face of it, there's no reason to use those tools for this particular job.

Comment: It would be a input of java but I can only define parameters, so the objectife is that  the person choose between FIRST, SECOND, or third

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what your question is about, but if you don't want to hard-code the value `"SECOND"` into your stylesheet and pass it as a parameter at runtime instead, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="theName"/>

<xsl:template match="/TR">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="COMPANY[@name=$theName]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```